# Python: C code for-loop that multiplies the loop variable

Tags: python, for-loop

The C code here:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 1000; i *= 3){
   //task
}
```

How can I write this in python with a for loop?
So far I can only think of a solution using while loops:

```
i = 1
while i <= 1000:
    #task
    i *= 3
```

Is there a way I can write this with a for loop in python?

Comment: What's the problem with a while loop? For-loops in python could be described as for-each therefore while is you'r best bet.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
step = 3

_i=1
for x in range(0,1000):
    if x%_i!=0:
        continue
    _i*=step

    # task
    print(x)
```

Comment: What's the reason for using modulus? You could just use `if x != _i:`

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.